# Specific Letters in LaTeX subsection titles

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I've been looking around for a bit now and have read several tutorials about incorporating letters in your numbering scheme or even the appendix function, but nothing to meet my specific needs.

For our laboratory experiments we need to structure our journals as following:

```
1. Generic task 1

P 1.1 Preparation for Task 1  
P 1.2 Preparation for Task 1  
E 1 Execution of Task 1  
R 1.1 Review of Task 1  
R 1.2 Review of Task 1  
R 1.3 Review of Task 1

2. Task 2

P 1.1  
...  
R 1.x
```

It seems like this is not exactly easy, but we are also given the requirement of using LaTeX, which I very much would like to do, but without the P/E/R prefixes the journals are looking very unorganised and that will definitely cost us some points. So, do you guys have any ideas here?

Comment: What type of interface are you looking for? For example, will all the elements within Task 1 *always* be pointing back to Task 1 (and never to, say, Task 2 or something else)?

Comment: That is correct!
For
X. Task X
we will always have subsections of
X.1
X.2 
and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following might be a start that can be expanded.

Tasks are portrayed as `\section`s, while the elements within a task (`\preparation`, `\execution` and `\review`) are `\subsection`s. Individual counters for each `\subsection` are used with an automated title

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3em}% Enlarged \subsection counters don't overlap with titles

\newcounter{preparation}[section]
\newcounter{execution}[section]
\newcounter{review}[section]

\newcommand{\task}{\section{Task \thesection}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\preparation}{%
  \let\c@subsection\c@preparation
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{P \thesection.\arabic{subsection}}%
  \subsection{Preparation for Task \thesection}%
}
\newcommand{\execution}{%
  \let\c@subsection\c@execution
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{E \arabic{subsection}}%
  \subsection{Execution of Task \thesection}%
}
\newcommand{\review}{%
  \let\c@subsection\c@review
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{R \thesection.\arabic{subsection}}%
  \subsection{Review of Task \thesection}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\task % Task 1
\lipsum[1]

\preparation % Preparation P 1.1
\lipsum[2]

\preparation % Preparation P 1.2
\lipsum[3]

\execution % Execution E 1
\lipsum[4]

\review % Review R 1.1
\lipsum[5]

\review % Review R 1.2
\lipsum[6]

\review % Review R1.3
\lipsum[7]

\task % Task 2
\lipsum[8]

\preparation % Preparation P 2.1
\lipsum[9]

\preparation % Preparation P 2.2
\lipsum[10]

\execution % Execution E 1
\lipsum[11]

\review % Review R 2.1
\lipsum[12]

\review % Review R 2.2
\lipsum[13]

\review % Review R 2.3
\lipsum[14]

\end{document}
```

The advantage of using the regular section units is that it easily fits within the `\tableofcontents` environment.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much!